# Building a factory that returns class instances instantiated with different parameters?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I'm building a small policy system for passwords and usernames. These policies can be configured based on a variety of different factors, but for the most part they're relatively straight forward. The policies all implement `IPolicy` which looks something like:

```
public interface IPolicy
{
    (bool, ErrorResponse) Verify(string input);
}
```

Some of the policies require certain parameters to be passed to them during instantiation, such as `minimumLength`. An example policy may look something like:

```
public class LowerCasePolicy : IPolicy
{
    private const string _defaultTitle = "LowerCaseCount";
    private readonly int _minimumLength;
    private readonly string _errorMessage;
    private readonly string _errorTitle;

    public LowerCasePolicy(int minimumLength)
    {
        _minimumLength = minimumLength;
        _errorMessage =
            $"Password does not meet the lower case character count requirement set by the password policy ({_minimumLength})";
        _errorTitle = _defaultTitle;
    }

    public LowerCasePolicy(int minimumLength, string errorMessage, string errorTitle = _defaultTitle)
    {
        _minimumLength = minimumLength;
        _errorMessage = errorMessage;
        _errorTitle = errorTitle;
    }

    public (bool, ErrorResponse) Verify(string input)
    {
        var enoughUpper = Regex.Matches(input, "[a-z]").Count >= _minimumLength;
        return !enoughUpper ?
            (false, new ErrorResponse(_errorTitle, _errorMessage))
            : (true, null);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build some sort of factory that's capable of returning all of my different policies with their different constructors, but I'm not too sure where to go from here. One potential option I came up with was to create a base `PolicyArgs` class to pass the parameters, and I could use derived classes for each. Like so:

```
public class PolicyArgs
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class LowerCaseArgs : PolicyArgs
{
    public int MinimumLength { get; set; }
}
```

And the constructor for the policy would now look like:

```
public LowerCasePolicy(PolicyArgs args)
{
    if (args == null)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    if (!(args is LowerCaseArgs lowerCaseArgs))
        throw new ArgumentException();

    _minimumLength = lowerCaseArgs.MinimumLength;
    _errorTitle = lowerCaseArgs.Title ?? _defaultTitle;
    _errorMessage = lowerCaseArgs.ErrorMessage ??  $"Password does not meet the lower case character count requirement set by the password policy ({_minimumLength})";
}
```

And the factory would look like:

```
public class PolicyFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Policy, Func<PolicyArgs, IPolicy>> _policyDictionary = new Dictionary<Policy, Func<PolicyArgs, IPolicy>>
    {
        [Policy.LowerCase] = (args) => new LowerCasePolicy(args)
    };

    public IPolicy Create(Policy policy, PolicyArgs args)
    {
        return _policyDictionary[policy](args);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is truly the best approach, or if there's some better option for handling different policies with different constructor needs. The goal is to be able to simply put these configurations in a database and have my `PolicyProvider` effectively return an array of `IPolicy`.

As suggested, another option is to use something akin to a dictionary to handle the additional parameters, such as:

```
public class PolicyArgs
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    // There's almost definitely a better way to handle this;
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalParameters { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

public LowerCasePolicy(PolicyArgs args)
{
    if (args == null)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    if (!args.AdditionalParameters.ContainsKey("MinimumLength"))
        throw new ArgumentException("Minimum Length is not provided.");

    if (!int.TryParse(args.AdditionalParameters["MinimumLength"].ToString(), out var minimumLength))
        throw new ArgumentException("Minimum Length is invalid.");

    _minimumLength = minimumLength;
    _errorTitle = args.Title ?? _defaultTitle;
    _errorMessage = args.ErrorMessage ??  $"Password does not meet the lower case character count requirement set by the password policy ({_minimumLength})";
}
```

This approach is great because it makes it incredibly easy to store the data as JSON either in the database or in the application configuration files. However, it has some distinct draw backs. For one, a type in any of the strings could be disastrous. It also requires me to manually handle the typecasting and checks.

I'm not opposed to this approach, but I feel like there are definitely better options out there.

The original usage (with strongly typed classes for each policy) looks like this:

```
public void TestPolicyFactory()
{
    var args = new LowerCasePolicy.LowerCaseArgs {MinimumLength = 1};
    var factory = new PolicyFactory();
    var policy  = factory.Create(Policy.LowerCase, args);

    Assert.IsNotNull(policy);
}
```

Changed for the dictionary it looks like:

```
public void TestPolicyFactory()
{
    var args = new PolicyArgs();
    args.AdditionalParameters.Add("MinimumLength", 1);
    var factory = new PolicyFactory();
    var policy  = factory.Create(Policy.LowerCase, args);

    Assert.IsNotNull(policy);
}
```

Comment: `PolicyArgs` looks good to me. It could have a Dictionary of additional parameters or something. Like the JSON, that lets you pass arbitrary stuff from config or whatever to the constructor, but it's at least somewhat strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you will get very opinionated answers to your questions so it may not fit stackoverflow rules.

My opinion:

I would give all my policies the same argument: a json in the form of a string. I would avoid inheritance because you will get into trouble to deserialize from your database into the correct type (database do not fit well with polymorphic collections).

once inside your class you can deserialize your json into your specific object and throw if it does not fit.

Comment: It's funny that you mention this, that was one of the very first things I thought of (effective a parameter string that gets deserialized). I was just hoping there was something a bit more strongly-typed solution that could help remedy the drawbacks to the json approach.